# jQuery hashchange how to do?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have made a jQuery thing; with will load content without refreshing the page. The code for that is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// initial
$('#content').load('content/index.php');

// handle menu clicks
$('#navBar ul li ').click(function(){
var page = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
$('#content').load('content/'+ page +'.php');
return false;
});
});
```

Now I want to have a sort of history thing in that, the code for that is:

```
(function(){
// Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
// hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
$(window).hashchange( function(){
var hash = location.hash;
// Set the page title based on the hash.
document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';
// Iterate over all nav links, setting the "selected" class as-appropriate.
$('#nav a').each(function(){
var that = $(this);
that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
});
})
// Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
// the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
$(window).hashchange();
});
```

Found on: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/

My Question is: how can i make the second code working with the first?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't gotten an answer yet I will write it. You need the plugin `jQuery hashchange` for the code to run.

https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link was only intended to show him where to download the required javascript files.

Comment: Still, just pointing one to a tool they can use does not really count as telling him how to do something.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a cache you could do something like

```
$('#content').load('content/index.php');
//create a cache object
var cache = {};
// handle menu clicks
$('#navBar ul li ').click(function(){
  var page = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
  //check if the page was already requested
  if(cache[page] === undefined){
     //if not fetch the page from the server
     $.get('content/'+ page +'.php', function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
        //save data in cache
        cache[page] = data;
  }else{
     //use data from cache
     $('#content').html(cache[page]);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This won't work, he don't wanna load the content, so I cannot check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [History JS](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). It works for HTML5 pushState and also falls back to HTML 4 hashtags. Also works for keeping the state model when the page is refreshed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MattThrower and what, exactly, would he include in this link?

Comment: @Qix it's an auto-message from the review system. Some code samples might, perhaps be useful?

Comment: @MattThrower I know exactly what it is. Code samples might be useful, but irrelevant since history.js has been around for a while and will be around for a long time.

Comment: @Qix an example solution to a question, perhaps.

Comment: Never known a better time to use the term "RTFM".